# is there any way i can automatically send push notifications when i add news to my firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

this is the java file that is used to add news to the fire base

```
public class newsadding extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("allNews");

    EditText date, name;
    Button btsave, btdelete, btshow;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newsadding);

        date =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
        name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);

        btsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSave);
        btdelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDelete);
        btshow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btShow);

        // save the record
        btsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String  n = date.getText().toString();
                String nom = name.getText().toString();
                try {
                    myRef.child("allNews").push().setValue(n+" : "+nom);
                    Toast.makeText(newsadding.this, "Record saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(newsadding.this, "Record not saved" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // delete a record

        btdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    String n = date.getText().toString();
                    String q = database.getReference().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(newsadding.this, "record deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(newsadding.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // show all records

        btshow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(newsadding.this, usernews.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the file that is used to show the information in a list view

```
public class usernews extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("allNews").child("allNews");
    TextView fullnews;

    ProgressBar loading;
    private ListView lsStudents;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usernews);
        loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
        lsStudents=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        fullnews=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullnews);
        fullnews.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Toast.makeText(usernews.this,
                 "يرجى التأكد من أنك متصل بالإنترنت إذالم تكن متصل بعد...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.

                final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // Get value from areaSnapShot not from dataSnapshot
                    String value1 = String.valueOf(areaSnapshot.getValue());
                    areas.add(value1);

                    if (lsStudents.equals(null)){
                        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (!lsStudents.equals(null)){
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                String value2 = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());    
                ArrayList<String> areas2 = new ArrayList<String>(areas);
                Collections.reverse(areas2);

                ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(usernews.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, areas);
                lsStudents.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
                lsStudents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) { 
                        fullnews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String newss = (lsStudents.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                        fullnews.setText(newss);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Toast.makeText(usernews.this,
                       error + "!!!!!خطاء في الاتصال !!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now i know that you can send information from the fire base from the notification bar that is on the fire base page but i don't want to add the information manually because my these pages in my app are for news and i cannot always do it manually because i'm not the only person that is adding those news so i need the app to show a simple bar that says new news and my application name and logo on the background with a message sound. can any one help ?

Comment: you can send notification directly from user device when he/she post news.

Comment: yes, i thought about this way that i use the  OnButtonClick of the add news button the message gets send  but the problem i don't know how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089148/send-push-notification-from-server-to-android-device-in-java

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Method to send Notifications from server to client end.
    public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "API_KEY_HERE";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    public static void pushFCMNotification( ) throws Exception {

        String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM; // You FCM AUTH key
        String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;

        URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + authKey);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("to","/topics/foo-bar");
        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("title", "FCM Notificatoin Title"); // Notification title
        info.put("body", "Hello First Test notification"); // Notification body
        data.put("data", info);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    }

btsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

pushFCMNotification();

            }
        });
```

Comment: thank allot for your help but can you guide me a Little more because i'm using firebase as my servers. how can i add this code to the fire base ? and how can i register all my device id to web server?? in my case the app is on app store and has a lot of users with different devices.

Comment: public static void sendNotificationToUser(String user, final String message) {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    final Firebase notifications = ref.child("notificationRequests");

    Map notification = new HashMap<>();
    notification.put("username", user);
    notification.put("message", message);

    notifications.push().setValue(notification);
}

Comment: I have edited the answer it will do your job and don't forget to vote.happy coding.

Comment: where should i use this method and why ist alwas giving an error on firebase and push word

Answer (score 1):

Every time you add some news, you can create a child in your database named "notifications" and to that you can add the title and the message of the notification you want to generate for the particular news item you posted.

Make sure that all of the users using your app subscribe to a certain topic.

Lastly, run a server sided script(I use Node.js for this purpose) that listens to the "notifications" child and every time a child is added to it, it takes a data snapshot, retrieves the title and the message, and sends a topic notification to the topic that your users are subscribed to.

As long as you have a service active in your app and it's running in the background, it will receive a push notification automatically.

For more information on topic notifications and the REST API for server communication, go [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#build_send_requests).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You have to register and subscribe to Topics in your client app .Once subscribed they will recieve notification .To send notification refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#build_send_requests) firebase tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Save your list count in shared preferences. Then check if your list count is more than last saved list count. If it is greater, then build a local notification & show your last added item of your list as a notification.
No need to push notification from Firebase everytime you change the data on Firebase.