# How to create java server set up for FCM send / receive notification messages

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a website which is developed in java (jsp/servlet/mysql), when one record is inserted into DB via website i want to send FCM send/receive notification messages to android app. But i dont know how to do this, can I create services for that or Servlet will be fine. please help me to create app server in java which handle send/receive messages from android app using FCM & how to save tokens in DB.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Searching on engines?

Comment: yes am able to send send Downstream message from my java server, but that time I was getting token from onTokenRefresh() and save it in DB manually. Also I asked to FCM support team they answered me - Currently, we don't have official guides in creating app server for Java apache tomcat, but I search on google and find some solutions but all are regarding the wamp server and PHP based services.

Comment: Setting up a Java server to send FCM messages to devices is a broad topic. But if you're looking for how to send a message through FCM in Java, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089148/send-push-notification-from-server-to-android-device-in-java

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your suggestion, but I want some guidance on handling XMPP protocol...

Comment: I want help on something like set up a Java server which connects to FCM, someone help me plz..