# firebase cloud messaging Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting error while sending message using `Firebase` cloud messaging admin `API`.

Error message is below

> Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>       {
>         "error": {
>           "code": 400,
>           "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
>           "errors": [
>             {
>               "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
>               "domain": "global",
>               "reason": "badRequest"
>             }
>           ],
>           "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
>         }
>       }

Let me put my admin configuration here..

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("My service accout file.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://deliveryeat-1aa42.firebaseio.com").build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Message sending code is below

```
// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
String registrationToken = "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";

// See documentation on defining a message payload.
Message message = Message.builder().putData("score", "850").putData("time", "2:45").setToken(registrationToken).build();

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
// Response is a message ID string.
System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

maven dependencies that i am using is following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So can anyone help me in this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that your `registrationToken` has an invalid format.  It should be 152 characters.

To confirm that, try building your message with [setTopic("test")](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder.html#setTopic(java.lang.String)) instead of `setToken(registrationToken)`.

Comment: Thank you Bob.  it is working with setTopic. But it still not working with registrationToken. any idea.

Comment: How are you obtaining the token?  Is it 152 characters?

Comment: i just put dummy token.

Comment: e.g. 
12345678911111234567891111123456789111112345678911111234567891111123456789111112345678911111234567891111123456789111112345678911111234567891111123456789

Comment: It has to be a valid token obtained from one of the client SDKs.  For example, [on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token), the method is `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.  The docs for getting the token on iOS [are here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#receive-the-current-registration-token).

Comment: it is working for the following token...
fESEZ9zwM-Y:APB91bGfLrfYavY_j-YM6hOEqs_-KEIuozw-BdjIfxeeGdFit1CQEBDftW8tLMrVCubb6XZ-hLjPx3YPF6KGuR0ve3Pm_fMkDiqQdeLN0QA2HXPPYviCTI93RAhWVBH8gdJo9joM9cvL

Answer (score 16):

Yet another cause of this is that your message is too large:

> Notification messages can contain an optional data payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB, except when sending messages from the Firebase console, which enforces a 1024 character limit.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: Thanks for this, my payload size exceeded 4KB. Reducing it worked!

Answer (score 8):

This error also occurs when trying to send a push-notification to an iOS simulator device.

Answer (score 7):

One possible cause for this is that the client and server are connected to different firebase projects. Project name appears in the google-services.json file on the client and in the credentials json on the server.

[Firebase FCM: invalid-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420582/firebase-fcm-invalid-argument/51078509#51078509)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that certain keys are not allowed in a notification data payload. Specifically, the key 'from' is forbidden.

[Firebase data message payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.DataMessagePayload)

Answer (score 0):

I had my project name uppercased in the URL (strange, because my project name is actually uppercased)

Answer (score 0):

I received this error trying to set the 'content_available' flag to true (which is what the docs say to do: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

Turns out you need it to be 'content-available' instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in `Condition` part.
I used invalid characters.

For example **wrong**: `03:00' in topics`